# PHP mail form - doesnt work for large attachments

Tags: php, forms, attachment

I created a form using PHP with the mail() function to send an attachment. It works for files under 1MB, and when no attachment is uploaded. However, it does not work for LARGER files.

I checked on stackoverflow, and everyone recommends checking my **PHP.ini** file. I've made the following changes to my php.ini (and have OVER COMPENSATED just to get this to work)...

```
memory_limit = 250M  
max_input_time = 300  
max_execution_time = 300
post_max_size = 30M  
upload_max_filesize = 30M
```

Below is how I built the headers and body...

```
    $filetmpname = $_FILES['fileupload']['tmp_name']; 
    $filename    = $_FILES['fileupload']['name'];
    $fileupload = $serverpath . basename($filename);
    $filesize    = $_FILES['fileupload']['size']; 
    $filetype    = $_FILES['fileupload']['type']; 
    $fileerror   = $_FILES['fileupload']['error'];

    $boundary = md5("random");

    
    $headers = "MIME-Version: 1.0\r\n" .
        "From: ". $theiremail."\r\n" . 
        "Cc: dj@djgallagher.com\r\n" . 
        "Reply-To: ".$theiremail."\r\n" .
        "Content-Type: multipart/mixed;" .  
        "boundary = $boundary\r\n";


        //read from the uploaded file & base64_encode content
        $handle = fopen($filetmpname, "r"); // set the file handle only for reading the file
        $datacontent = fread($handle, $filesize); // reading the file
        fclose($handle);                 // close upon completion
        $data = chunk_split(base64_encode($datacontent));

        $body = "--$boundary\r\n" . 
        "Content-Type: text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1\r\n" .
        "Content-Transfer-Encoding: quoted-printable\n\n" .  
        $textcontent . "\n\n";
        // "Content-Transfer-Encoding: base64\r\n\r\n" . 
        // chunk_split(base64_encode($textcontent));
        
        $body .= "--{$boundary}\r\n" .
        "Content-Type: $filetype; name=".$filename."\r\n" . 
        "Content-Disposition: attachment; filename=".$filename."\r\n" . 
        "Content-Transfer-Encoding: base64\r\n" . 
        "X-Attachment-Id: ".rand(1000, 99999)."\r\n\r\n" . 
        $data."\n\n"; // Attaching the encoded file with email
```

In addition, when I **run mail(), the email doesn't go through, but no error comes** up (no output for $errorMessage below)... Note: the email goes through with smaller files.

```
$ok = mail($toaddress, $subject, $body, $headers);  
if (!$ok) {
    $errorMessage = error_get_last()['message'];
    echo "Message Failed. Error:";
    echo $errorMessage;
} else {
    echo "Message Sent";
}
```

When I var_dump($_FILES) I get a array, so the attachment is recognized ...

```
array(1) {
  ["fileupload"]=>
  array(5) {
    ["name"]=>
    string(46) "mapimage1p2.jpg"
    ["type"]=>
    string(10) "image/jpeg"
    ["tmp_name"]=>
    string(14) "/tmp/phpVwAQJQ"
    ["error"]=>
    int(0)
    ["size"]=>
    int(1331087)
  }
}
```

Once again... this works for small attachments, but not larger. Anyone have any idea how to fix this? Or what to ask my webhost?

Comment: Please show how you're creating the attachment in the mail. It would probably be best to use a library like PHPMailer instead of rolling your own attachment code.

Comment: Many mail systems have a limit on message size. What's the limit on your server?

Comment: Posted some clarification above... As for the server limit, I'd need to check. However, I've been testing only 1-2MB files (which should NOT have an issue). Anything under 1MB works fine.

Comment: That sure sounds like there's a 1-MB limit in the mailserver.

Comment: Have you checked the mailserver log?

Comment: For one of the larger files (less than 2MB), the mailserver log says....
-----
20230912T194053: www.mywebsite.com/contact.php 
[21756] Cannot send message: Too big 
----
My webhost is saying that its a "scripting" issue.  But I dont see any error in my code, or why it would be my fault (I'm sending a file... and the server is blocking it)

Comment: Looks like your SMTP has a limit on the size of mails it will accept, so you will either have to ask your hoster whether that can be increased, or you might need to use a different SMTP (something external, maybe rather in combination with a library such as PHPMailer, than coding it all yourself.)